# get url for a manually uploaded image file to Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I'm wring a kotlin android app.
I want to show some images in a recycle-view.
I have uploaded them in Firebase Storage.
I have cloud Firebase collection which has a field "image".
I normally use Glide to load images from Firebase, but it uses a URL.
I have the file location:
"gs://myapp.appspot.com/image.png"
How would I be able to convert this to be able to use it in Glide?
Glide
.with(context)
.load(model.image)
.centerCrop()
.placeholder(R.drawable.holder)
.into(holder.itemView.iv_image)

Comment: Build a reference to the object, and use that reference to get a download URL, as shown in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files

Answer (score 0):

If you use [FirebaseUI for Storage](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/storage/readme/), you can load the image into a view with:

```
StorageReference ref = FirebaeStorage.instance.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://myapp.appspot.com/image.png");
Glid.with(context).load(ref).centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.holder).into(holder.itemView.iv_image)
```

If you don't want to use FirebaseUI, you'll have to translate the path you have to a download URL yourself by calling `ref.downloadUrl` as shown in the documentation on [downloading data from a URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) (that Doug also linked).

Comment: sorry. that didn't work for me. it would just show the same url. anyway I just find a link in Firestore storage, when I click on the file it would give a url link with token. so thanks. problem solved.